# Graph theory possibilities

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Is it possible to have a simple graph(no loops or parallel edges), connected, six vertices, six edges?

Is it possible to have a graph, connected, ten vertices, nine edges, nontrivial circuit?

Is it possible to have a graph, six vertices, five edges, not a tree?

Comment: Have you tried coming up with counterexamples to any of these. If you draw some graphs and try to come up with counterexamples, either you will find one, or you will discover why there are none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first consider a hexagon.

For the second consider a path with ten vertices.

For the third consider a pentagon and an isolated vertex.

---

Edit: The number of graphs with $n$ vertices and $k$ edges (If the vertices have allready been labelled) is $\binom{\binom{n}{2}}{k}$. This number is positive for  values of $k$ between $0$ and $\binom{n}{2}$

Comment: I someone has references regarding the number of isomorphism types of graphs with $n$ vertices and $k$ edges I would be interested in it.

Answer (score 0):

1) All cycles have $n$ vertices and $n$ edges.

2) No. A connected graph with $n$ vertices and $n-1$ edges is a tree. Therefore, it cannot have a circuit.

3) See $C_{3} \cup P_{3}$, where $C_{3}$ and $P_{3}$ are disjoint. So $C_{3}$ has three vertices and three edges, then $P_{3}$ has three vertices and two edges.